# How to show some text with clicking id

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi everyone i want to ask you something.

I am trying to make a popup window. My popup window is working fine. But if is possible anyone can tell me How do I withdraw some text in popup window.

For example i have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/ByPRRN)**.

You can see in this demo there is a *JohDoe1,JohnDoe2,JohnDoe3* and *JohnDoe4* and also there is a *Click to show name in popup* link.

I want to learn how can i withdraw that name (*JohDoe1,JohnDoe2,JohnDoe3* and *JohnDoe4*) when i click (*Click to show name in popup*) link

Javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var i;
    $('.vd_button').click(function(){
      i = $(this).attr('id');
      $('.vduzalani, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
      $('.vvalan').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
      $('.vduzalani, .vvalan').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.vkapat').click(function(){
      close_box();
    });

    $('.vduzalani').click(function(){
      close_box();
    });

  });

  function close_box()
  {
    $('.vduzalani, .vvalan').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
      $('.vduzalani, .vvalan').css('display', 'none');
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="vduzalani"></div>
    <div class="vvalan">
      <div class="vkapat">✖</div>
      <div class="bilgidegistirmealani">
        The name should be here
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="5">Jogn Doe1</div>
    <div class="show_name vd_button" id="5">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="6">Jogn Doe2</div>
     <div class="show_name vd_button" id="6">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="7">Jogn Doe3</div>
     <div class="show_name vd_button" id="7">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="8">Jogn Doe4</div>
     <div class="show_name vd_button" id="8">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, bind a click event to those divs with class names of "show_name". When clicked grab their "prev" sibling's text and use that text to update the dialog's text. With jQuery, that is pretty easy and straight forward:

```
$('.show_name').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).prev().text();
    $('.bilgidegistirmealani').text(text);
    //open dialog here
});
```

Comment: Oh answer was very simple.I felt bad :/ . Thanks for this clean answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample solution:

```js
$('.show_name').on('click', function() {
  var text = $(this).siblings('.name').html()
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vduzalani"></div>
    <div class="vvalan">
      <div class="vkapat">✖</div>
      <div class="bilgidegistirmealani">
        The name should be here
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="5">Jogn Doe1</div>
    <div class="show_name vd_button" id="5">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="6">Jogn Doe2</div>
     <div class="show_name vd_button" id="6">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="7">Jogn Doe3</div>
     <div class="show_name vd_button" id="7">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divcont">
    <div class="name" id="8">Jogn Doe4</div>
     <div class="show_name vd_button" id="8">Click To show name in popup</div>
  </div>
</div>
```